# RichTextBox Using UNIX Newline

Tags: .net, vb.net, richtextbox, newline

I am using  RichTextBox control in my application, and I am saving the contents of it to the hard drive. The text in the RichTextBox control contains some "vbNewLine" constants. The file saves successfully, but the "vbNewLine" becomes a Mac OS X/UNIX style newline (one not recognized by Notepad). The newlines display correctly while in the RichTextBox, but when I save the file, they don't appear. I am using VB.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `RichTextBox`, **you should save your file in *.rtf format**.

However, **you can save it in *.txt format** with [`RichTextBox.SaveFile(String, RichTextBoxStreamType)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4a710b1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
RichTextBox1.SaveFile("", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```